# WPF, any easy way to work with different screen resolutions?

Tags: wpf

Given a WPF Application running full screen, a fair amount of controls some of which will animate from off screen to center. I was wondering if there are any special ways to save on the amount of time required to optimize an application for different screen resolutions?

For example, using Blend I've setup some text, which is originally off screen to scroll into view. Now in design mode the start positions are static. If resolution changes the start positions will obviously not be correct.

So I guess to correct this, during app startup. I need to

1. Check resolution
2. Move the text box to the desired start location
3. Adjust the storyboard as required, so the frames all have correct co-ordinates depending on the res of the screen.

I don't mind doing all of this, but if there is an easier way please share!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF [layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) of controls should be made in such way, that when size of window or content changes, controls automaticaly resize/reposition themselves to reflect this change.
This is highly affected how your layout is made, especialy by using specific [panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx), that do layout of their child elements.

This is also made obvious by using device-independent units for sizes, margins and sometimes positions of controls. And also allows different kind of zooming and scaling of whole UI without any need to redesign the whole thing.

If you are trying to position your controls absolutely, either by using Canvas panel or margins, your are doing it totaly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, scene is measured in abstract units, not pixels, and controls are freely scaled. There should be no problems to center something, or what?